# Is there a way to change the default Swift REPL prompt?

Tags: swift, emacs

I've been using the `swift-mode` and the Swift REPL under Emacs to
program in Swift.  Unfortunately, the Swift REPL doesn't expect a
"dumb terminal" and issues a lot of `ESC` terminal control sequences
to format its prompt nicely, e.g. `ESC [J` `ESC [1G ESC[J 1> ESC [1G
1> ESC [1G 1> ESC [6G`.  This is rather disturbing under Emacs.

Is there a way to set the Swift REPL prompt differently, similarly to
setting a [Bash prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)?

Comment: Now also asked on swift-users: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20161003/003517.html.